# Is 飲んだことがない identical to 飲まなかったことがある?

Tags: grammar, negation

When two or more verbs (or adjectives) can be "bounded" (either loosely or tightly) as the following case,

- 食べていない。
- 買ってくれて欲しい。
- したことがある。

does the negated position matter?

More precisely, for example:

- Is 「食べていない」identical to 「食べなくている」?
- Is 「買ってくれて欲しくない」identical to either 「買わなくてくれて欲しい」or 「買ってくれなくて欲しい」?
- Is 「したことがない」identical to 「しなかったことがある」?

## Bonus question:

Is there a rule specifying the only part that can be negated?

Comment: What do you mean by 買ってくれて欲しい?

Comment: You say simply 買って欲しい.

Comment: You mean 買ってもらいたい, no?

Comment: 私はあなたに車を買ってくれて欲しい。

Comment: I want you to buy a car for me.

Comment: @YasashiiEirian 欲しい is (technically an adj. but putting it aside) "want" in "I want a car." e.g. "want to **get**". 買ってくれる implies "I/we get", so using the them together is intrinsically redundant.

Comment: @broccoliforest: How about 買って下さらせて欲しい。I want you to buy for me?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity "I want you to buy for me" translates into あなたに買ってもらいたい, and its honorific form is あなたに買って**いただき**たい.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentences 飲んだことがない and 飲まなかったことがある are different.

飲んだことがない is translated as "I have never drunk", and 飲まなかったことがある is translated as "There were times when I didn't drink."

The negative form of 食べていない is 食べていなくない, and 食べていない is identical to 食べないでいる.

The negative form of したことがある is したことがない. The negative form of したことがない is したことがなくない but it is rarely used. したことがない and しなかったことがある are different as I explained.

買ってくれて欲しい is unnatural. If you want to say "I want you to buy a car for me", it is "私に車を買って欲しい". The negative form of 買って欲しい is 買って欲しくない, and 買って欲しくない is identical to 買わないで欲しい.

In addition, 食べないでいない and 買わないで欲しくない are rarely used.

They are summarized as follows:
"Negative verb + verb" has the same meaning as "verb + negative verb" like 走らないで行く and 走って行かない and they are translated as "go without running".

And "negative verb + negative verb" is rarely used.

Here is a related question: [して行｛い｝かない versus しないで行｛い｝く](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30515/%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%A1%8C-%E3%81%84-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-versus-%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E8%A1%8C-%E3%81%84-%E3%81%8F/30529#30529)

Comment: I am still confused with the 欲しい grammar. Consider, 私はあなたにネギを早く切って欲しい。I think it means that "I want you to cut the onion quickly.". Therefore, "I want you to buy a car for me." should be 「私はあなたに私のための車を買ってほしい。」.

Comment: Yes, you are right. 私のための車を買って欲しい and 私のために車を買って欲しい is almost same meaning. And  this 私に means 私のために.

Comment: Last, 「しなくて行く」and「しないで行く」have the same meaning?

Comment: I think しないで行く is common, しなくて行く is unnatural.