# I don't understand the translation order of スカートは試着して買わないと心配だ。

Tags: grammar, translation, て-form, negation, scope

I think how to translate this could be...
① スカートは
② 試着して
③ 買わないと
④ 心配だ
That should make the translation go...
"The skirt, I tried it on, If I don't buy, I feel worried."

But in the book it says...
"If I don't try the skirt on before I buy, I'll get worried."

Could anyone explain which word I should translate in the correct order? What grammar is this sentence using?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30534/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/86788/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82372/9831

Comment: @Chocolate OMG! thank you so much!