# Negation in concurrent verbs

Tags: grammar, て-form, negation, scope

I saw this sentence in my workbook:

> スープは音を立てて飲まないのがいいマナーとされる。

and I found many cases of 音を立てて飲まない on Google.

This expression seems to mean "to not drink, while making sounds", instead of "to drink without making sounds", for which I would use 音を立てずに飲む.

What is the grammar point of such expression? Is this an exceptional or general case?

Comment: As an aside, that statement is not even true of Japan.  One of the first things foreigners learn in Japan is that slurping noodles is not rude.  Strange that a Japanese workbook would have that.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30534/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This expression seems to mean "to not drink, while making sounds"

I think this is where you went wrong. Think of 音を立てて飲む as one block, and you have a negation of that whole block. So more like

( NOT ( 音を立てて飲む  ) = いいマナー ) とされる。

Of course, your 音を立てずに飲む is also correct, I prefer this version myself. However, they are both correct.

Comment: Are there any parallel examples of negating a whole block of verbs?

Comment: @Kotoba How about.... https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30534/9831 「宿題をしていかない生徒が多い」「遊んで暮らすな」「物を口に入れてしゃべらないでください」, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82383/9831 「試着して買わないと心配だ」「箸を使ってご飯を食べません」「勉強してテストを受けなかった」「歩いて学校に行かない」, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/86788/9831「解いてから帰らないとすっきりしない」「加熱してから食べないといけません」「予約してから行かないと待たされます」「化粧を落としてから寝ないと肌に悪いですよ」「体を洗ってから湯船に入らないとダメですよ」「お互いのことをよく知ってから結婚しないと、うまくいかないと思います」