# What does the きた in this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar, subsidiary-verbs

> 今度は何を覚えてきた?

Mother said to her daughter that just got back home

I wanna interpret it as "what did you learn? (and got back here home)?" but i don't know if that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're corret. This -きた (past form of くる) is a [subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) that indicates the listener "comes", or "brings the result of remembering". You usually don't need to translate this type of くる into English.

Related:

- [What does やってくる mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95301/5010)
- [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)